# Compile error: undefined symbol: apply

Tags: smart-contract

I am following the tutorials on EOS's Developer's Portal.  My EOS build was successful.  I initially had errors with BOOST but it ran fine when I installed it the second time.

This is the code from helloworld.cpp from the tutorial:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]] /* eosio.cdt won't know about the hi() action without an attribute */
      void hi( account_name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
      }
};
EOSIO_ABI( hello, (hi)) /* EOSIO_ABI macro to handle the dispatching of actions for the hello contract */
```

When I tried to compile with the following command:

```
eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen
```

I get the following error:
***/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: undefined symbol: apply***

Can someone please help me understand this and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

use `eosiocpp -o hello.wast hello.cpp`
and after this use `eosiocpp -g hello.abi hello.cpp` 
to compile contract

Comment: Thank you!  That worked although, for me it was eosin-cpp instead of eosiocpp.

Comment: `eosio-cpp` and `eosiocpp` are different tools. the latter is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while following the EOS tutorials, it appears that not all of them are up to date. In my case I tried updating to the latest(currently) EOSIO v1.7.0 and EOSIO.CDT v1.6.1, cloned the project, rebuild it, installed everything as stated here: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit and the problem was solved. Hope it helps.