# eosio-cpp Compile error: undefined symbol: apply

Tags: eosiocpp

[Compile error: undefined symbol: apply](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/compile-error-undefined-symbol-apply)

I got the exact same problem as above but the alternative command doesn't work for me. I don't have eosiocpp instead of eosio-cpp. Can anybody please help me?

same logs here:

```
➜  ~/Code/contracts/hello$ eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen
```

/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: undefined symbol: apply